# Projection onto the Stiefel manifold and the orthogonal Procrustes problem

Tags: orthogonality, matrix-analysis, stiefel-manifolds, procrustes-problem

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m \ge n$, the case with $m >n$ being particularly interesting to us. The Stiefel manifold is
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{S}^{m, n} = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} : X^T X = I_n\}.
\end{equation}
Given matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times m}$, the orthogonal Procrustes problem is
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{min} \{\|A- BX\|_F  : X \in \mathbb{S}^{m,n}\}. 
\end{equation}
When $l = m$ and $B = I_m$, the problem reduces to finding the projection of $A$ onto the Stiefel manifold, namely
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{min} \{\|A- X\|_F  : X \in \mathbb{S}^{m,n}\}. 
\end{equation}

**Question 1**:
Is it true (particularly when $m >n$) that the optimal value for the projection problem is
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dist}(A, \mathbb{S}^{m,n}) = \| \sigma(A) - \mathbf{1} \|_2 \quad (\mathbb{R}^n \ni \mathrm{1} = [1, 1, ..., 1]),
\end{equation}
which is attained by
\begin{equation}
X^* = UV^T
\end{equation}
with $A = U\Sigma V^T$ being a **thin** singular value decomposition of $A$? Here, $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$ lie in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, respectively. If yes, where can I find an **exact** reference with a proof?

**Question 2** (A generalization of **Question 1**).
Is it true (particularly when $m >n$) that one of the optimal solutions for the orthogonal Procrustes problem is given by
\begin{equation}
X^* = UV^T
\end{equation}
with $B^TA = U\Sigma V^T$ being a **thin** singular value decomposition of $B^T A$? Here, $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$ lie in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, respectively.  If yes, where can I find an **exact** reference with a proof? [*Update (20220715): The answer is **no**. See my answer posted below.*]

**Question 3**. If the Frobenius norm is changed to the induced $\ell_2$ operator norm, is the optimal solution known? If yes, where can I find an **exact** reference with a proof?

Thank you very much!

Remarks.

1. [Higham, [Matrix Nearness Problems and Applications](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/%7Ehigham/narep/narep161.pdf), Th. 4.1] does provide a positive answer to **Question 1**, and even a partial answer to **Question 3**. However, it does not contain any proof or reference for this theorem. Even though the author is quite trustworthy, I dare not rely on solely such a reference.
2. These orthogonal Procrustes discussed in [Absil, Mahony, Sepulchre, *Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds*, Sec. 2.2.2], [Horn, Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, 2nd Edition, Sec. 7.4.5], and [Golub, Van Loan, *Matrix Computations*, 3rd Edition, Sec. 12.4.1]. However, only the solution to the **balanced** case ($m=n$) is mentioned. If the unbalanced case admits the same solution, why should they skip it? This fact makes me unsure about the answer to **Question 2**.
3. My attempt for **Question 1**.

**Proof** (a positive answer to **Question 1**).
Since
\begin{equation} 
\|A - X\|_F^2 = \|A\|_F^2 +\|X\|_F^2 - 2\mathrm{Tr}(A^T X)
=\|A\|_F^2 + n - 2\mathrm{Tr}(A^T X),
\end{equation}
minimizing $\|A-X\|_F$ is equivalent to maximizing $\mathrm{Tr}(A^T X)$. Setting $Y =  U^T X V \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we have
\begin{equation}
Y_{i,i} = U_i^T X V_i \le  \|U_i\|_2\|X\|_2\|V_i\|_2 = 1, \quad 
i = 1, 2, ..., n,
\end{equation}
where $Y_{i,i}$ is the $(i,i)$ entry of $Y$, while $U_i$ and $V_i$ are the $i$-th column of $U$ and $V$ respectively. By straightforward calculations,
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\mathrm{Tr}(A^T X) = &\mathrm{Tr}(V\Sigma U^T X) \\
= &\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma U^T X V) \\
= &\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma Y)\\ 
= & \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(A) Y_{i,i}\\
\le & \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(A),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the equality holds when $X = X^* = UV^T$. Hence the optimality of $X^*$ is justified. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dist}(A, \mathbb{S}^{m,n})
= \|A - UV^T\|_F
= \|U\Sigma V^T - UV^T\|_F
= \|\Sigma - I_n\|_F
= \|\sigma(X) - \mathrm{1}\|_2.
\end{equation}
Q.E.D.

Of course, **this proof follows quite standard techniques** (it is for example almost the same as the proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem), which seems to assume that $m = n$ according to "This quantity $S$ is an orthogonal matrix").

However, if such a simple and clean answer to such a basic question (**Question 1**) is correct, it must have been included in papers and textbooks. Why could not I find such a reference? I must have overlooked something, either a flaw in my proof, or a reference.

4. One may consider another orthogonal Procrustes problem formulated as
   \begin{equation}
   \mathrm{min} \{\|C- YD\|_F  : Y \in \mathbb{S}^{m,n}\},
   \end{equation}
   where the data is $C \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times l}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times l}$. In the balanced case ($m = n$), this formulation is equivalent to the abovementioned formulation with $C = A^T$, $D = B^T$, and $Y = X^T$.
   However, this formulation **does not have a "truly unbalanced" case**: if $m > n$, then we can set $\bar{D} = [D^T ~0]^T\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times l}$, and consider
   \begin{equation}
   \mathrm{min} \{\|C- Z\bar{D}\|_F  : Z \in \mathbb{S}^{m,m}\},
   \end{equation}
   the first $n$ columns of its solution being a solution to the problem with $D$ in the place of $\bar{D}$.
   Moreover, even if $m >n$, we can still solve the problem directly by the same technique presented above (**if it is correct**), noting that
   \begin{equation}
   \|C - YD\|_F^2 = \|C\|_F^2 + \|YD\|_F^2 - 2 \mathrm{Tr}(C^TYD) = \|C\|_F^2 +\|D\|_F^2 - 2\mathrm{Tr}(YDC^T). 
   \end{equation}
   In this way, we find that a global solution to this problem is $Y^* = UV^T$, where $CD^T = U\Sigma V^T$ is an SVD of $CD^T$ with $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. However, this **does not** answer our **Question 2**. In addition, the technique does not apply anymore, as $\|BX\|_F \neq \|B\|_F$.

Comment: [A generalized solution of the orthogonal procrustes problem](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02289451) (1966)

Comment: Hi @RodrigodeAzevedo ! Thank you very much for your comment. I am aware of this paper, but it deals with only the balanced case. See the first line under (1.3): "$A$ and $E$ are both $n\times m$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positive answer to **Question 1**:

The answer is yes, and the proof included in the post is correct.

See a summary of related results in Section 2.1 of [Tight Error Bounds for Nonnegative Orthogonality Constraints
and Exact Penalties, Chen, He, and Zhang, 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.05164).

Indeed, the matrix $X^*$ specified in **Question 1** is a projection of $X$ onto $\mathbb{S}^{m, n}$ under any **unitarily invariant norm**, not only the Frobenius norm. This result is due to Fan and Hoffman in the square case (see [Theorem 1, Ky Fan and A. J. Hoffman. Some metric inequalities in the space of matrices. Proc. Amer.
Math. Soc., 6:111–116, 1955]).

**Theorem** (Fan-Hoffman 1955, see [Theorem 8.4, N. J. Higham. Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation. SIAM, Philadelphia, 2008]). Suppose that $X = UP$ is a polar decomposition of a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ ($m \ge n$). Then
\begin{equation}
\|X - U\| = \min\{\|X - V\| \mathrel{:} V \in \mathbb{S}^{m, n}\}
\end{equation}
for any unitarily invariant norm.

Note that the theorem also answers **Question 3**.

In the sequel, I will give a brief proof of this theorem. The proof is different from the one in [Higham 2008], but the basis is the same, which is the following lemma. This lemma is due to Mirsky in the square case (see the proof of Theorem 5 in [L. Mirsky. Symmetric gauge functions and unitarily invariant norms. Q. J. Math., 11:50–59,
1960]). See [my post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427518/majorization-for-singular-values-of-the-difference-of-two-matrices-sigmaa) for more discussion on this lemma.

For two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, recall that $y$ weakly majorizes $x$, denoted by $x\prec_w y$, if the sum of the $k$ largest entries of $x$ is smaller than or equal to that of $y$ for each $k \in\{1, ..., n\}$.
For any matrix $A$, we use $\sigma(A)$ to denote the vector consisting of the singular values of $A$ in descending order.

**Lemma 1** (Mirsky 1960, see [Theorem 3.4.5, R. A. Horn and C. R. Johnson. Topics in Matrix Analysis. Cambridge University Press,
Cambridge, 1994]) For any matrices $X, Y \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, we have $|\sigma(X) - \sigma(Y)| \prec_w \sigma(X-Y)$.

We also need the following fundamental results.

**Lemma 2** (von Neumann 1937, see [Theorem 3.5.18, R. A. Horn and C. R. Johnson. Topics in Matrix Analysis. Cambridge University Press,
Cambridge, 1994]). $\|\cdot\|$ is a unitarily invariant norm on $\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ ($m \ge n$) if and only if there exists a symmetric gauge function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|X\| = g(\sigma(X))$ for
all $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

**Lemma 3** (Fan 1951, see [Theorem 4, Ky Fan. Maximum properties and inequalities for the eigenvalues of completely continuous
operators. Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA, 37:760–766, 1951]). Given two nonnegative vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $g(x) \le g(y)$ for any symmetric gauge function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $x \prec_w y$.

**Proof of the theorem**. It suffices to prove that
\begin{equation}
\|X - U\| \le \| X - V\| \quad \text{for all} \quad V \in \mathbb{S}^{m, n}. 
\end{equation}
According to Lemmas 2 and 3, we only need to show that
\begin{equation}
\sigma(X - U) \prec_w \sigma(X - V).
\end{equation}
To see why this inequality holds, we note that
\begin{equation}
 (X-U)^\top (X-U)
= X^\top X + U^\top U - X^\top U - U^\top X
= P^2 + I - 2P = (P-I)^2,
\end{equation}
which implies that
\begin{equation}
\sigma(X-U) = \sqrt{\lambda((P-I)^2)} =  |\lambda(P-I)| = |\sigma(X) - \mathbf{1}| = |\sigma(X) -\sigma(V)| \prec_w\sigma(X-V),
\end{equation}
where the last step invokes Lemma 1. The proof is complete.

Remark: Question 1 can also be answered by the trace inequality of von Neumann's.

**Lemma 4.** (Theorem 1, von Neumann 1937, see [R. D. Grigorieff. A note on von Neumann’s trace inequality. Math. Nachr., 151:327–328,
1991]) For any matrices $X \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, we have $|\mathrm{tr}(X^H Y)| \le \sigma(X)^\top \sigma(Y)$.

According to Lemma 4, for any $V \in \mathbb{S}^{m, n}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\|X - V\|_F^2 = \|X\|_F^2 + \|V\|_F^2 - 2\mathrm{tr}(X^\top V) 
\ge \|\sigma(X)\|_2^2 + \|\mathbf{1}\|_2^2 - 2\sigma(X)^\top \mathbf{1}
= \|\sigma(X) - \mathbf{1}\|_2^2.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Answer to **Question 2**. No. Consider
\begin{equation}
A = I_2,
\quad 
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & M & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Let $B^T A = U\Sigma V^T$ be a thin SVD of $B^TA$ with $U\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. We will show that $\bar{X} = UV^T$ is **never** a global solution to
\begin{equation}
\min\{\|A-BX\|_F : X \in \mathbb{S}^{3,2}\},
\end{equation}
as long as $M >> 1$.

Note that
\begin{equation}
B^T A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & M \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Thus $U$ must have the form of
\begin{equation}
U = \begin{bmatrix} W \\ 0\end{bmatrix} 
\quad \text{with} \quad W \in \mathbb{S}^{2,2}. 
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
\bar{X} = UV^T  = \begin{bmatrix} WV^T \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|A - B\bar{X}\|_F &=
\left\|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & M 
\end{bmatrix} WV^T
\right\|_F\\
&\ge 
-\left\|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\right\|_F +
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & M 
\end{bmatrix} WV^T
\right\|_F \\
& = - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{1 + M^2}\\
& \approx M.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, taking
\begin{equation}
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{S}^{3,2},
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|A - B\bar{X}\|_F &=
\left\|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\right\|_F = 1 < \|A - B\bar{X}\|_F. 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

For analysis of the unbalanced orthogonal Procrustes problem, see
[Elden, Park, A Procrustes Problem on the Stiefel Manifold, 1997].